# how do I disable the overflow hidden feature only for one column in a datatable

Tags: css, datatable

I am using the [datatable](http://datatables.net/) plugin in my application. Using the following custom CSS, I have hidden text-overflow for all columns in the datatable.

```
.init
body { font-size: 140% }     
table.dataTable th,
table.dataTable td 
{
    max-width:120px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;  
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Now when I try to implement a drop-down button on each row, the drop-down part is also getting hidden due to this custom style. 
The code I am using for the drop-down button is:

```
<td>
<div class="btn-group" >
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Action <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Delete</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Versions</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>                                          
</td>
```

Is there any way that I can disable the overflow-hidden attribute only for the column where I implement the drop-down button.....

Comment: The column in which the drop-down buttons are present....That is the only <td >I have specified in the code above

Comment: what i mean is if you can determine if it's first, second, third column etc you can target just that column with css using :nth-child(n)

Comment: ok.....it would be the 9 the column

Comment: @ Mia Sno, the :nth-child(n) worked, thanks

Comment: @MiaSno, is there a way I can keep the overflow hidden for all columns except the 9th column. A help would be highly appriciated